# How can I access to a variable defined in a "child" environment of a package from another function in R?

Tags: r, package, environment

I created a new environment as a "child" of a package environment because the package vars are locked on the attach. How can I get to the variable I assigned to that env from another function in the program?

So in one function I have:

```
 taralli_cache<-new.env(parent = as.environment("package:taralli"))
 taralli_cache$data_man <- data_management
```

How can I access to the data_man? I tried with get() but I have to feed the right env object and I can't in that separated function.

Thanks very much for any kind of help!

Comment: Why do you do this?

Comment: in order to have a package-wide variable set after attaching

Comment: Established procedures are not an option? https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages

Comment: you mean saving a file .rdata with this lonely variable?